# Getting Access Token from facebook with publish_stream

Tags: c#, facebook

I tried this:

```
        oAuthClient = new FacebookOAuthClient(FacebookApplication.Current);
        oAuthClient.RedirectUri = callBack;
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters.Add("permissions", "offline_access,publish_stream");
        var loginUri = oAuthClient.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
```

this brings me the access token , i save it in Database

now i try to post to facebook doing this :

```
        var postparameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        postparameters["message"] = tweet;
        postparameters["name"] = "This is a name";
        _fbClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
        var result = _fbClient.Post("/me/feed", postparameters);
```

problem is this tells me that im not authorized to post. so in order to make it work i have to visit this url :

```
http://www.facebook.com/authorize.php?api_key=[key]&v=1.0&ext_perm=publish_stream
```

this also have a problem cause this link doesnt redirect back !

so the question is how i do get the access token from the first place with the publish_stream permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
parameters.Add("permissions", "offline_access,publish_stream");
```

to

```
parameters.Add("scope", "offline_access,publish_stream");
```

Comment: OP should probably go ahead and read this document in its entirety: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication - a lof of the authentication code changed in October 2011 with the move to Oauth 2 and the code in the question appears to predate that change